# why can't I import geopandas?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

My only line of code is

```
import geopandas
```

and it gives me the error

```
OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file
```

has anyone encountered this before? my script was working just fine until this error came up.

**Note that rtree module not found was an issue fisrt, and upon installation I received the above error instead.

Comment: You need to install `spatialindex`. https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/1.-Getting-Started

Comment: thanks! That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue while working in Linux Subsystem at Windows 10 (speaking [about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)). What helped was installing the version for *developers* using `apt`. Namely:

`sudo apt install libspatialindex-dev` did the job.

I did not need to work with `make`.

*edit: Nice to see my answer has been upvoted so many times; in the time of writing it, however, this was not the most popular answer and it was preceeded by the other answers that suggested using `make`. This is why I am referring to this command; and I think the other answers are worth reading anyway.*

Comment: any spatialindex packages for centos?

Answer (score 14):

If you are using MacOS, it's as simple as follow:

```
brew install spatialindex
pip install rtree
```

If you are working on linux environment you have to build this from [source](http://libspatialindex.github.io/install.html):

1. Install spatialindex

   ```
   curl -L https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/archive/1.8.5.tar.gz | tar xz
   cd libspatialindex-1.8.5/
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

2. install rtree:  `pip install rtree`

Comment: This worked for me on my mac and after quite a while, trying to find a solution (including editing the core.py file in rtree) I am very greatful. I conda installed geopandas, pip installed osmnx, brew installed spatialindex, pip uninstalled rtree and then pip installed rtree and it worked.

Comment: Left out one step: need to run `./autogen.sh` before you can `./configure`.

Answer (score 6):

Linux installation steps for Docker users:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing curl autoconf libtool automake
RUN curl -L https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/archive/1.8.5.tar.gz | tar -xz
RUN cd libspatialindex-1.8.5 && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install && ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

User DYZ provided the correct answer in the comments.

> You need to install [spatialindex](http://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/1.-Getting-Started).

This question should be set to answered so it is not misleading