# OSError: libspatialindex_c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, redhat, geopandas

I am deploying a python script in a EC2 server running a redhat linux variant. I'm trying to install geopandas dependencies [libspatialindex](https://libspatialindex.org/install.html) and [rtree](https://pypi.org/project/Rtree/)

I followed the instructions to install libspatialindex:

```
$cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ec2-user/ 
$make
$make install
```

and it creates two folders: `include` and `lib`. `lib` contains `libspatialindex_c.so.4` but I have no idea how to correctly reference this folder or where it should be located. I read that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` could be set in the bash profile but I had no luck with this. I did this: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/lib`, which doesn't seem right but it did not do anything.

My current `PATH` is set to `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin`

When do I get this error?

```
pip3 install --user rtree
OSError: libspatialindex_c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[This](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/120) suggests using an older version of rtree
`pip install "rtree>=0.8,<0.9"`. There's no error in installation but then this ends up happening:

```
>>>import rtree
OSError: libspatialindex_c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>import geopandas
OSError: libspatialindex_c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[why can't I import geopandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516181/why-cant-i-import-geopandas) was a similar problem and got me to this point. I have `libspatialindex_c.so.4` but I need to know where to place this file. I have other scripts on this instance, so anaconda is not a solution. I tried to install linuxbrew but there were other problems with that.

Comment: Try to do `find $HOME -name libspatialindex_c.so.4` and put the directory found in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Philippe I get these directories: 
`/home/ec2-user/usr/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.4`
`/home/ec2-user/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.4`
`/home/ec2-user/libspatialindex-1.8.5/bin/libspatialindex_c.so.4`
`/home/ec2-user/libspatialindex-1.8.5/.libs/libspatialindex_c.so.4`
How should i export my path? I installed it twice, once in my root directory and one in home/ec2-user/usr/ which is a folder that didnt exist before

Comment: try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/usr/lib`

Comment: It worked! I would have sworn I wrote something like that but thank you so much!